# Ambiguous method in Java 8, why?

Tags: java, generics, java-8, java-7, ambiguous

```
public static void main(String... args){
    then(bar()); // Compilation Error
}

public static <E extends Exception> E bar() {
    return null;
}

public static void then(Throwable actual) { }

public static void then(CharSequence actual) { }
```

Compilation result (from command line `javac Ambiguous.java`)

```
Ambiguous.java:4: error: reference to then is ambiguous
        then(bar());
        ^
  both method then(Throwable) in Ambiguous and method then(CharSequence) in Ambiguous match
1 error
```

Why this method is ambiguous? This code compile with success under Java 7!

After changing method bar to:

```
public static <E extends Float> E bar() {
    return null;
}
```

This compiles without any problems, but is reported as error in IntelliJ Idea (Cannot resolve method `then(java.lang.FLoat)`).

This code fails under Java 7 - `javac -source 1.7 Ambiguous.java`:

```
Ambiguous.java:4: error: no suitable method found for then(Float)
        then(bar());
        ^
    method Ambiguous.then(Throwable) is not applicable
      (argument mismatch; Float cannot be converted to Throwable)
    method Ambiguous.then(CharSequence) is not applicable
      (argument mismatch; Float cannot be converted to CharSequence)
1 error
```

Java version

```
java version "1.8.0_40"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_40-b25)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.40-b25, mixed mode)
```

Comment: Will it help if I say that i've just successfully run your code with jdk1.8.0_40? Just pasted it to a fresh Idea project and clicked 'run' with junit annotation imported. The first one obviously -version with Float is definitely wrong on any java version, as per error you see.

Comment: @marvin82: in [*try Java8*](http://www.tryjava8.com/app/snippets/552436d9e4b017c2ee13ca34) it fails.

Comment: marvin82, it **compiles** fine with Float under java8, there is no error https://gist.github.com/mariuszs/0a82ca08f55499906ea9

Comment: My bad, i had language level overriden. Sorry for confusion.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Consider the following class:

```
public class Foo extends Exception implements CharSequence {
    //...
}
```

The class `Foo` implements both `Throwable` and `CharSequence`. So in case `E` is set to this instance, the Java compiler does not know which method to call.

The reason there is probably no problem for *Java7* is that generics are less implemented. In case you don't provide an `E` yourself (e.g. `(Foo) bar()`), Java will fall back on the basic verion of `E` which is `implements Exception`, `E` is thus only considered to be an instance of `Exception`.

In [*Java8*](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/8-whats-new-2157071.html), the [*type inference* is improved](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/genTypeInference.html), the type of `E` is now derived from the parameter called for by `then()`, in other words the compiler first looks what possible types `then()` needs, the problem is that they both are valid choices. So in that case it becomes ambiguous.

---

**Proof of concept**:

Now we will slightly modify your code and show how ambiguous calls are resolved:

Say we modify the code to:

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String... args){
        then(bar()); // Compilation Error
    }
    public static <E extends Exception> E bar() {
        return null;
    }
    public static void then(CharSequence actual) {
        System.out.println("char");
    }
}
```

If you run this in **Java8**, there is no problem (it prints `char`), because Java8 simply assumes there is such class `Foo` (it created some kind of "inner" type for it that derived from both).

Running this in **Java7** yields problems:

```
/MyClass.java:18: error: method then in class MyClass cannot be applied to given types;
    then(bar()); // Compilation Error
    ^
  required: CharSequence
  found: Exception
  reason: actual argument Exception cannot be converted to CharSequence by method invocation conversion
1 error
```

It did a fallback on `Exception` and couldn't find a type that could deal with it.

If you run the original code in **Java8**, it will error because of the ambiguous call, if you run it in **Java7** however, it will use the `Throwable` method.

---

In short: *the compiler aims to "guess" what `E` is in Java8, whereas in Java7 the most conservative type was picked.*

Comment: so, in this case we should avoid mixing interfaces with classes?

Comment: @MariuszS: well you can make explicit (for instance with `(Exception) bar()` about which `E` you are talking. But in general maxing (non `final`) `class`es with `interface`s and `interface`s with `interface`s is looking for trouble I guess.

Comment: @MariuszS: No, generally, you should avoid to declare methods like `E bar()` which basically say “the caller can decide what `bar()`” returns. Since the only valid return value that can hold this promise is `null`, such methods make no sense.

Comment: @Holger: well in C# you can also add a `new()` constraint. In that case you force there should be a default constraint available. In that case, it becomes useful. As far as I know, that's not available in Java8, but eventually it can be implemented.

Comment: @CommuSoft: but when the method is ambiguous, how does C# know which type to instantiate? In Java 8 you can do such thing by adding a `Supplier<E>` parameter to `bar()`, then the caller can use `then(bar(DesiredType::new))` to disambiguate by providing the appropriate `Supplier` at the same time…

Comment: @Holger: because in C# you are forced to provide the type explicitly, unless it is a `this` type (*extension methods*). I'm only saying that in the (near) future such `E` could become interesting (for reasons we do not yet know). Don't get me wrong, did +1 on your comment, currently it's not a good idea, but one must be careful with such statements I think.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem can you explain why in Java 8 it worked for `<E extends Float> E bar()` scenario? Float being a final class, it never can be subclassed. Therefore in that case how a class Like `Foo` (extends Float and implements CharSequence ) exists?