# Why does this code fail with sourceCompatibility=1.8

Tags: java, generics, java-8

The following code works when compiled with sourceCompatibility=1.7 or 1.6, but fails after switching to 1.8:

```
public class Java8Wat {
  interface Parcelable {
  }

  static class Bundle implements Parcelable {
    public void put(Parcelable parcelable) {
    }

    public void put(Serializable serializable) {
    }

    public <T extends Parcelable> T getParcelable() {
      return null;
    }
  }

  static {
    Bundle inBundle = new Bundle();
    Bundle outBundle = new Bundle();

    outBundle.put(inBundle.getParcelable());
  }
}
```

Compilation output:

```
Java8Wat.java:23: error: reference to put is ambiguous
        outBundle.put(inBundle.getParcelable());
             ^
both method put(Parcelable) in Bundle and method put(Serializable) in Bundle match
```

Here's the repo with failing code: https://github.com/chalup/java8-wat. Just invoke `./gradlew clean build` from project directory.

I skimmed through JLS for Java 8, but I haven't found anything relevant.

Additional observation: the code compiles if I change the `getParcelable()` signature to:

```
public Parcelable getParcelable()
```

Why does java compiler considers `put(Serializable)` to be potentially applicable method for `outBundle.put(inBundle.getParcelable())` call and what changes should be made to Parcelable/Bundle class? Bonus question: why does this error happens only on Java 8 and not on Java 7?

Comment: Related: [Ambiguous method in Java 8, why?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29499847/ambiguous-method-in-java-8-why)

Comment: I was going to post an answer. Oh well. ;p

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would suggest that this is due to changes in how inference is done in java 8. And to the fact that `Parcelable` is an interface.
Because of this, the infered return type of `getParcelable` results in an ambiguous call because the infered return type can be applied to both methods.

I would mainly refer to this other question for a clearer explanation : [Why can this generic method with a bound return any type?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29670018/why-can-this-generic-method-with-a-bound-return-any-type)

As of to the real understanding of how the inference works in this specific case and why it is different between java 7 and 8, this would require a deeper study of the [inference part](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-18.html) of JLS.

Comment: It works in Java 7 because Java 7 only inferred type arguments based on a return target if it was subject to assignment conversion. Otherwise the upper bound gets inferred. In other words, the fact that one call is inside the other like `f(g());` is why there is a difference. In Java 7, `put(Serializable)` can't be applicable this way.

Answer (score 1):

As the Message says the `reference to put is ambiguous`.

You have to explizity cast the value so that the compiler knows wich method you would like to use:

```
outBundle.put((Parcelable)Bundle.getParcelable());
```

or

```
outBundle.put((Serializable)Bundle.getParcelable());
```

Comment: That's a workaround, but what I want to know is why the compiler assume that the return type of `getParcelable` is `Serializable`, which leads to ambiguity.

Comment: but why's there difference between java 8 and earlier ones?

Comment: This answer only addresses one part of the two (or three) part question.

Comment: If we're talking about "how do I made this code compile?" workaround, obviously the cleaner solution would be adding explicit type argument to getParcelable call.

Comment: @Jens hasn't the subject of the question the same all the time? This answer does not address that.